# How to keep a div, with an image, on the same line as another div with text

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm having a hard time getting my blue add image to be on the same line as the letters of the alphabet. As you can see here, it always shows up below the alphabet:

[image]

This is the HTML, showing my latest attempt (white-space:nowrap):

```
<div style="width:900px">
    <fieldset>                
        <div style="width:900px"><h2>abook</h2></div>
        <div class="center" id="headerAlphabet" style="white-space:nowrap"></div>
    </fieldset>
</div>
```

Below is my ready function in JavaScript. The loop creates the letters of the alphabet by appending to a div. Then, when it adds the add image, that ends up on a new line.

This is my latest attempt, showing `float:left`. I've also tried `display:block` and `display:inline`. I've also tried putting those in the anchor tag. And I've tried other things that I don't recall now.

```
$(function () {
    // Show the letters of the alphabet, with a link to call GetEntries() for each of them.
    for (var i = 65; i <= 90; i++) {
        $('#headerAlphabet').append('<a href=\"#\" onclick=\"GetEntries(\''
            + String.fromCharCode(i) + '\')\">'
            + String.fromCharCode(i) + '</a> ');
    }

    $('#headerAlphabet').append('<a href=\"#\" onclick=\"AddEntry()\">'
            + '<img src=\"/Scripts/Home/add.png\" title=\"Add contact\" style=\"float:left\" /></a>')
});
```

Every solution, that I've found, says to do what I've attempted above, but nothing is working. How can I get my add image on the same line as the alphabet?

Comment: What does the rendered HTML look like?

Comment: @j08691: The picture at the top of my question.

Comment: No, what does the final HTML code look like.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/VKmN7/

I am guessing you are using a css reset, or something like it, setting all `img` tags to `display:block;`. Set your appended img to `display:inline;`:

```
a img { display:inline; }
```

Comment: That did it. Although I wanted the image on the right (you couldn't tell from my question). This is the result: http://jsfiddle.net/ufdJH/.

Answer (score 0):

If the image sits within a < a > tag, try floating the < a > tags left.

Then just make sure that there is enough room for them all to fit, 900px may not be enought.